# MacOS wc (wordcount) counts wrong words with UTF-8 character Å

Tags: macos, utf-8, locale, wc

When using `wc` on the string `Ås` (swedish letter capital Å) I get wordcount 2 when I expected wordcount 1.

Counting the words `Å`, `sÅ` gives 1, which feels correct.

```
$ echo sÅ | wc
       1       1       4
$ echo Å | wc
       1       1       3
```

Counting the words `Ås`, `sÅs` gives 2, which does not feel correct.

```
$ echo sÅs | wc
       1       2       5
$ echo Ås | wc
       1       2       4
```

It is only the letter `Å` which can reproduce this, not any of `åäöÄÖ`.

```
$ echo "Ås" | wc
       1       2       4
$ echo "Äs" | wc
       1       1       4
$ echo "Ös" | wc
       1       1       4
```

I use default Locale settings from Mac OS when starting up the Terminal, it looks like this:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I get the same results on MacOS Sierra and Lion.

Just checking how the string `Ås` looks like.

```
$ echo "Ås" | hexdump
0000000 c3 85 73 0a                                    
0000004
```

---

So, is it a matter of locale settings and Mac OS sets it up the wrong way - at least regarding to the command `wc`?

Is it a bug in Mac OS version of `wc` regarding UTF-8 character `Å`?

Or, when using (the default of) `wc -c`, the character 85 is detected as a white-space character being the ellipsis `…` in the ASCII table? (`wc -m` however provides the expected answer for wordcount)

Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can confirm identical results when I test interactively ... and add that when I SSH to a remote FreeBSD server, my copy-and-paste looks like `echo "\303\205s" | wc` ... and reports only one word. (The `wc` in OS X/macOS derives from an older version of FreeBSD's `wc`.) HOWEVER .. if I test a *file* on OS X, I get different results. Try: `echo "Ås" > test.txt; wc -w test.txt`. I have no idea why this occurs. Looking forward to informative answers.

Comment: Ah, also stumble onto this problem with the Swedish characters. One work-around is to convert to latin1 before counting with `wc`... `echo -n "sÅÄÖs" | iconv -t latin1 -f utf8 |  wc` yields `0       1       5`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed ! It is a matter of locale setting - UTF_8 is a variable length encoding scheme.
Straight latin1 chars (old Ascii ones) are encoded 1 byte whereas accented swedish characters 2 bytes (or more?) check in particular the A with ring. Hope it helps